error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8) under ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
I'm trying to clone rpcs3 and when updating the submodules, I'm getting this error.
user@comp:~/rpcs3$ git submodule update
Cloning into '/home/user/rpcs3/3rdparty/llvm/llvm'...
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 20 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git' into submodule path '/home/user/rpcs3/3rdparty/llvm/llvm' failed
Failed to clone '3rdparty/llvm/llvm'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/home/user/rpcs3/3rdparty/wolfssl/wolfssl'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): Error decoding the received TLS packet.
error: 5802 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl.git' into submodule path '/home/user/rpcs3/3rdparty/wolfssl/wolfssl' failed
Failed to clone '3rdparty/wolfssl/wolfssl'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/home/user/rpcs3/3rdparty/llvm/llvm'...
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 2927 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git' into submodule path '/home/user/rpcs3/3rdparty/llvm/llvm' failed
Failed to clone '3rdparty/llvm/llvm' a second time, aborting

I found the answers here error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1) but neither setting git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400 nor setting git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1 helped. In the latter case the error just slightly changes to
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

the line error: X bytes of body are still expected shows a different amount of bytes each time I run the command
running on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS with git version 2.34.1

How long does it run before you get this?

@Jim Redmond It's random and each time different. Cloning with --depth 1 gives me a higher chance of succeeding after a while, but for large repositories with many submodules it's still a problem
